# LaTeX citation style

Tags: citing

How can I do the style of citation in LaTeX like this:

(Abran et al. 2013)

I used

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}   
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}

\citep(abran)

\bibliographystyle{Apalike}
\bibliography{References}
\end{document}
```

and the result like this 
(Abran et al., 2013)

How I can remove the comma between the author name and the year

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: \documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}   
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}

\citep(abran)

\bibliographystyle{Apalike}
\bibliography{References}
\end{document}

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Googling for 'natbib comma' yielded a pointer at LaTeX community: [natbib | (Author Year) citation (no comma)](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&p=51349)

Using that and searching the [natbib](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/natbib.pdf) manual for 'comma' yields results in section 2.9 (Selecting citation punctuation), and a MWE of:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{aysep={}}
\begin{document}

\citep{KandR}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{refs}

\end{document}
```

[image]